# UIView Zoom in/out with UIScrollView using UITapGestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to do zoom in/out of my `UIView`, but when i zoom the view,,, my custom scrollview doesn't work means I am not able to scroll my view...

```
     self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=1.0;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=2.0;
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*2, self.view.frame.size.height*2)];
self.scrollView.delegate=self;

[self.scrollView addSubview:self.view];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tripleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTripleTap:)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tripleTap];

-(void)handleTripleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)g
{    
     if(self.scrollView.zoomScale > self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale)
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale animated:YES];
else
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale animated:YES];
}


- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.view;
}
```

Please help me in it...

Thanks....

Comment: have you set your scrollview's frame?

Comment: @chancy, yes,,, i updated my question with frame...